# Appium iOS|| org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command

Tags: ios, appium

I am runnning my automated test on Mac for iOS with Appium.

Getting following error while running it:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The application under test with bundle id '' is not running, possibly crashed (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 11.27 seconds
>
> Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
>   System info: host: 'Mac-mini-4.local', ip: '10.104.149.32', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.5', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
>   Driver info: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver
>   Capabilities [{app=, networkConnectionEnabled=false, databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=iPhone 6s, platform=MAC, platformVersion=null, webStorageEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=false, automationName=XCUITest, browserName=, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, udid=28f82f2f74d229a0e6de0922e8411f57bc759445, platformName=iOS}]
>   Session ID: 70e66892-82d6-41cc-a05c-369e859fa982
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>       at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:40)
>       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>       at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteWindow.getSize(RemoteWebDriver.java:914)
>       at com.commonLibraries.AppiumActions_iOS_Refactor.setScreenSize(AppiumActions_iOS_Refactor.java:675)
>       at com.commonLibraries.AppiumActions_iOS_Refactor.swipeDown(AppiumActions_iOS_Refactor.java:369)

I tried on a different Machine and it worked fine.
However does not for this one machine.

Also i tried reinstalling Appium on this machine. However was of no use.

Need assistance in figuring out the issue.

Thanks ..!

Comment: Looked closer i see that the problem is with driver.manage().window().getSize();
Dimension dm = IOSAppiumConnection.driver.manage().window().getSize();
  HEIGHT = dm.getHeight();
  WIDTH = dm.getWidth();
  CENTER_X = WIDTH / 2;
  CENTER_Y = HEIGHT / 2;
  System.out.println("Device dimensions are : Height: " + HEIGHT + "\n Width: " + WIDTH);
  System.out.println("Center of device dimensions are :" + CENTER_X
    + "\n" + CENTER_Y);
where:
Dimension dm = IOSAppiumConnection.driver.manage().window().getSize();

is throwing a unknown exception on one mac mini and works on another

Answer (score 0):

**I finally resolved the issue.**
It was due to some misconfiguration in the WDA.
As the exception was around `An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.`
I suspected it must have to do with the WDA.
*The Configured the WDA in xcode and build the WDA project and it worked fine.*